# How to SSH a remote switch with username and password?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh

I want to SSH to a remote switch and I only have an IP, Username, and Password. After installing SSH on my ubuntu machine, I tried to use: `$SSH username@ip`, but it keeps prompting without any responses. I then used `$sshpass -p [Password] ssh Username@IP` ,but it did the same.

It's a remote switch that running on a friend's lab. I only have 3 things about that switch public IP, Username and Password. My question is: Am I using the right ssh command? Do I need to do other configurations on my machine to ssh that switch?

Comment: I would be shocked if that switch was configured to allow remote clients to connect to it.  Are you sure you friend has properly configured this switch?

Comment: Using `ssh` for access to switches is common.  IMO, for security, access should be limited, perhaps to a subnet or specific set of machines, but that's not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're not actually typing the dollar sign at the prompt, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Many (older) switches configured to use `ssh` for access don't pay attention to the username provided at the command line of the client.  All access is typically through the same "console"-like terminal that is granted to `ssh`, `telnet`, and serial-console, equivalently.

In other words, you are doing it right, but the switch won't do what you want.

Additionally, some Dell switches I've used that support SSH keys, use those keys as a form of 2FA, still requiring a username and password in **addition** to the key.